# How do I remove an array inside an array in mongoDB?

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I need to remove an array **that is inside another**, found only query's to delete an array element (without him being inside another).
 
How do I delete a specific element (the ID) of the array what's inside this array? What's wrong with my query I get error?
 There is a better way to solve this? Without being an array within an array

Document

```
{
    "_id" : "8d127e9ca7178f900dc4953725188da9",
    "dataCriacao" : "2015-05-11T09:10:56.251-0300",
    "pecas" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "49919187a3c4871923dcda506eef5f73",
            "path" : null,
            "nome" : "Whirlpool_LinhaBranca_Positivo_CanaisdeAfinidade_SuperBanner_-.swf",
            "pathOriginal" : "1401 Pecas Midia Grafica_v2/Whirlpool_LinhaBranca_Positivo_CanaisdeAfinidade_SuperBanner_-.swf",
            "imagem" : null,
            "comentarios" : [ 
                {
                    "id" : "c1c586be8ded3d044f96fccc18473cf8",
                    "comentario" : "teste comentario",
                    "horario" : "2015-05-11T09:11:55.399-0300"
                }, 
                {
                    "id" : "dfc10dc2029ad93cf9585a3ecb3ebe51",
                    "comentario" : "teste comentario",
                    "horario" : "2015-05-11T09:11:55.418-0300"
                }, 
                {
                    "id" : "3ef39b18f6d7dc45d6d6f7ccb27a2e10",
                    "comentario" : "teste comentario2",
                    "horario" : "2015-05-11T09:12:11.124-0300"
                }, 
                {
                    "id" : "72b88be895da0b9b7f66c7be55d3ae3b",
                    "comentario" : "teste comentario2",
                    "horario" : "2015-05-11T09:12:11.140-0300"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "b22b488ed7302995fa2971d69f425516",
            "path" : null,
            "nome" : "Whirlpool_LinhaBranca_Positivo_DeskMedia_Widget_-.jpg",
            "pathOriginal" : "1401 Pecas Midia Grafica_v2/Whirlpool_LinhaBranca_Positivo_DeskMedia_Widget_-.jpg",
            "imagem" : null
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "846bf4984f533b46de83b0fea1b1e06d",
            "path" : null,
            "nome" : "Whirlpool_LinhaBranca_BuscaDescontos_Homepage_Cupom_-.jpg",
            "pathOriginal" : "1401 Pecas Midia Grafica_v2/Whirlpool_LinhaBranca_BuscaDescontos_Homepage_Cupom_-.jpg",
            "imagem" : null
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "5574d989005d89f9181ae1d4acffd7b3",
            "path" : null,
            "nome" : "Whirlpool_LinhaBranca_BuscaDescontos_Homepage_SuperBanner_-.swf",
            "pathOriginal" : "1401 Pecas Midia Grafica_v2/Whirlpool_LinhaBranca_BuscaDescontos_Homepage_SuperBanner_-.swf",
            "imagem" : null
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "3cddcc834c466e945fe5a97ecb75cbf3",
            "path" : null,
            "nome" : "Whirlpool_LinhaBranca_Positivo_DeskMedia_Widget.jpg",
            "pathOriginal" : "1401 Pecas Midia Grafica_v2/Whirlpool_LinhaBranca_Positivo_DeskMedia_Widget.jpg",
            "imagem" : null
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "cebfef8ed985551560cfd72ac72535dd",
            "path" : null,
            "nome" : "Whirlpool_LinhaBranca_Zoom_Newsletter_Destaque_-.jpg",
            "pathOriginal" : "1401 Pecas Midia Grafica_v2/Whirlpool_LinhaBranca_Zoom_Newsletter_Destaque_-.jpg",
            "imagem" : null
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "60a64c5154c79379a6c1c6cb1685ead6",
            "path" : null,
            "nome" : "Whirlpool_LinhaBranca_Positivo_CanaisdeAfinidade_Retangulo_-.swf",
            "pathOriginal" : "1401 Pecas Midia Grafica_v2/Whirlpool_LinhaBranca_Positivo_CanaisdeAfinidade_Retangulo_-.swf",
            "imagem" : null
        }
    ],
    "validacaoId" : "55509b6dccf2d4a2f3545fcb",
    "email" : "daniela.morais@sofist.com.br",
    "instancia" : "sofist",
    "tipo" : "3"
}
```

Query 1

```
db.getCollection('validacao_permalinks').update(
    {_id: "8d127e9ca7178f900dc4953725188da9"}, 
    {
        $pull: { "pecas.comentarios": {
            $elemMatch: {id:"c1c586be8ded3d044f96fccc18473cf8"}
            }
        }
     }
 )
```

Error

```
cannot use the part (pecas of pecas.comentarios) to traverse the element
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here Is the solution try this,

```
db.getCollection('validacao_permalinks').update(
    {'pecas.comentarios.id': "c1c586be8ded3d044f96fccc18473cf8"}, 
    {
        $pull: { 'pecas.$.comentarios': {
            "id":"c1c586be8ded3d044f96fccc18473cf8"}            
        }
     }
 )
```

This `{'pecas.comentarios.id': "c1c586be8ded3d044f96fccc18473cf8"},`  will find the document,

Then `$pull` will remove that document form the array.

Here are the some other references to the MongoDB Remove functionality

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/

Answer (score -2):

Here is my working example:

Floors is collection which contains array of rooms, this query removes "room" object with specified ID:

```
db.floors.update(
   { _id: ObjectId("547dc92e85fca4dc0b0c6f26") },
   {
        $pull: { rooms: {
            _id: ObjectId("547dc94685fca4dc0b0c6f29")
            } }
   },
   {upsert:false }
)
db.floors.find()
```